# Expresión regular en una condición [JAVA]

Tags: java

¡Hola buenas!

¿Cómo puedo decir que si el atributo `isbn` no empieza por `978-84-` me haga X cosa?

He pensado en usar una expresión regular, no sé si es la mejor opción, igual tiene algo java que me conviene más usar.

Un saludo.
¡Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```
public Llibre(String isbn, String titol, Date publicacio, Autor autor) {
        super();
        if (isbn == null || isbn != /* Si no empieza por "978-84-" */) {
            this.isbn = "978-84-???????-?";
        }
        this.isbn = isbn;
        if (titol == null || titol.isEmpty()) {
            this.titol = "AnonyousTitol";
        }
        this.titol = titol;
        if (publicacio == null) {
            this.publicacio = "Data nula";
        }
        this.publicacio = publicacio;
        if (publicacio == null) {
            this.publicacio = "Autor nul";
        }
        this.autor = autor;
    }
```

Comment: Pon el código no una imagen, así nadie te va a contestar

Comment: Replicar el problema de alguien usando una imagen es mucho más dispendioso. El código, los errores, los datos de prueba y la salida esperada se indican como texto. No eres novato en SO, ya deberías saberlo.

Comment: Ya está, ya he puesto la clase, jajaja, lo siento, pensaba que no era necesario poner el codigo ya que la duda se entiende bastante bien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar la función `startsWith` de la clase `String` con un not:

```
if (isbn == null || !isbn.startsWith("978-84-")) {
      this.isbn = isbn;
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!